# how to get tinymce value in javascript?+ Drupal7

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using drupal7 form

```
$form['subject'] = array('#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Subject'),
        '#maxlength' => 200,
        '#size' => 100,
        '#required' => TRUE,
);

$form['body'] = array('#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => t('Body'),
        '#type' => 'text_format',
        '#base_type' => 'textarea',
        '#format' => 'full_html',
        '#required' => TRUE,

);
```

we used tinymce editor. Posting form with jquery like this

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/myevent/preview',
            data: $('#eventform').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                $('#eventdata').html(data);
            }
        });
```

At my local its working fine, but on server, I couldn't get value of body textarea.

Comment: "I couldn't get value of body textarea" - that's a bit broad statement. Your ajax request was not sent? Was sent, but without data needed? Was sent, but never reached the server? Was sent, but reached the server malformed? And so on... These things only you can test. And most of them is not Drupal-related anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this I suppose this may help.

> tinyMCE.triggerSave();
>
> $('`#textarea-selector-id`).val();

i suppose that your text area would be inline:TRUE; 
change the text area to a div this may work

or

```
var editor='textarea-selector-id';
var content =tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
alert(content);
```

Comment: I am getting old content in post

Comment: I am  getting content - but its content which I first time added and in Post I get this content-
<p>test email<br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>

Comment: Sorry for this am not clear with your comments but i suppose you are not getting the value  so better try this